# Merge partial duplicate rows into one in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
Select * from testtable;
```

[image]

You can see that there are duplicate rows when we only consider 4 columns.
Can we simply make it one row and split two attribute values(mobile numebr & values(OM or OD only)) as two separate columns so that duplicates are removed like below?
[image]

```
create table testtable 
(
ACCOUNT_NUM VARCHAR2(30), 
OTC_ID NUMBER(9), 
OTC_SEQ NUMBER(9), 
OTC_MNY NUMBER(9), 
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE VARCHAR2(30)
);

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 381, 1, 1000, 'OM');

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 381, 1, 1000, '07400004483');

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 382, 2, 1000, 'OD');

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 382, 2, 1000, '07400004483');

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 397, 3, 3000, 'OD');

insert into TESTTABLE (ACCOUNT_NUM, OTC_ID, OTC_SEQ, OTC_MNY, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
values ('0000000191', 397, 3, 3000, '07800000688');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate OM/OD values from others. One option is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    account_num, 
    otc_id, 
    otc_seq, 
    otc_mny,
    max(case when attribute_value in ('OM', 'OD') then attribute_value end) 
        as attribute_value_1,
    max(case when attribute_value not in ('OM', 'OD') then attribute_value end) 
        as attribute_value_2
from testtable
group by account_num, otc_id, otc_seq, otc_mny
order by account_num, otc_id, otc_seq, otc_mny
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=160113689bcdd718f2ebc538077343e9)**:

```
ACCOUNT_NUM | OTC_ID | OTC_SEQ | OTC_MNY | ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_1 | ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_2
:---------- | -----: | ------: | ------: | :---------------- | :----------------
0000000191  |    381 |       1 |    1000 | OM                | 07400004483      
0000000191  |    382 |       2 |    1000 | OD                | 07400004483      
0000000191  |    397 |       3 |    3000 | OD                | 07800000688
```